# Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '(LongPressGesture.Value) -> Void' (aka '(Bool) -> ()')

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to pass an action as a function into the `.onEnded` modifier but when I attempt to, I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '(LongPressGesture.Value) -> Void' (aka '(Bool) -> ()')
```

If I pass the function within a closure, it works just fine but I'm not a big fan of that because it takes up more space and I should just be able to pass it directly in to the modifier I would think.

```
// This works
LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.25).onEnded {
    startTimer()
}

// This throws the error.
LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.25).onEnded(startTimer)
```

Comment: I'm surprised the first one works... it should give an error "Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change your `startTimer` signature to accept `LongPressGesture.Value` (which resolves to `Bool`):

```
func startTimer(_ value : LongPressGesture.Value) {
    //
}
```

```
LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.25).onEnded(startTimer)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked... will accept when able to.